# Índice em JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

Eu tenho uma tabela onde posso adicionar linhas dinamicamente, toda vez que clico no botão eu adiciono uma nova linha para preenchimento do campo, minha primeira linha vem com índice 0

```
<td><input type="text" name="data[Ticket][0][descricao_ticket]" size="20" placeholder="Informe aqui"></td>
```

Minha primeira informação eu gravo normalmente no banco de dados, mas quando preciso adicionar uma nova linha preciso ir no JS e alterar o índice 0 para 1 para que não sobrescreva a informação, como faço para deixar esse índice incrementar sozinho quando solicitar uma nova linha? Não manjo muito de javascript

```
(function($) {
    remove = function(item) {
      var tr = $(item).closest('tr');

      tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
        tr.remove();  
      });

      return false;
    }
  })(jQuery);

(function($) {
    AddTableRow = function() {

      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";
      //var indice = 0;

      cols += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Ticket][1][descricao_ticket]" size="20" placeholder="Informe aqui"></td>';

      cols += '<td>';
      cols += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="remove(this)">Remover</button>';
      cols += '</td>';

      newRow.append(cols);
      $("#details-table").append(newRow);

      return false;
    };
  })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode contar quantos elementos `input` a `id` `#details-table` possui e acrescentando `+1` no total:

```
var indice = $("#details-table input[type='text']").length+1;
```

E concatenar na variável:

```
cols += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Ticket]['+indice+'][descricao_ticket]" size="20" placeholder="Informe aqui"></td>';
```

### Dica

Pode concatenar a variável `cols` desta forma abaixo para enxugar o código:

```
cols += '<td><input type="text" name="data[Ticket]['+indice+'][descricao_ticket]" size="20" placeholder="Informe aqui"></td>'
+'<td>'
+'<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="remove(this)">Remover</button>'
+'</td>';
```

Comment: Show de bola, deu certinho, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @Henrique Valeu! Só uma obervação: quando vc remover uma linha, o indice irá diminuir de novo. Vai dar problema?

Comment: Não tem problema, o importante é apenas não sobrescrever a informação, desta forma me atende perfeitamente.

Comment: @ÐvÐ e Henrique, uma pergunta: tem necessidade de se preocupar com o indice? Porque pode ser usado o recurso de array do atributo name do input text: name="data[Ticket][descricao_ticket][]". Assim todos os inputs com o nome com 'nome_input[]' são submetidos como um array.

Comment: @pss1suporte Teoricamente faz sentido, mas teria que ver com o Henrique se cabe na programação dele.

Comment: @ÐvÐ, sim por isso eu não postei a minha resposta. A sua ficou mais coerente com a pergunta, isto é, ficou mais pertinente. E não é teoria. Geralmente eu uso assim mesmo! Sempre que necessito deste tipo de solução, eu uso o array no nome do input text mesmo e não sobre escreve os dados.

Comment: @pss1suporte Acho válido postar a sua resposta sugerindo o que vc considera melhor, mesmo não sendo exatamente o que foi perguntado, e, claro, explicando o porquê de fazer da forma que sugere. Mesmo que não ajude na pergunta ou não for ser útil ao autor da pergunta, pode ser válido no futuro para outras pessoas.